# How can I edit value of 1 column based on previous value of other column pandas within each group

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have two columns start date and end date.
For every row need to edit my start date column value as previous row value of end date column.

eg:
[original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjkZk.jpg)

my new dataframe should be like 
[new dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk9Ga.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: please don't share image for question